# how to write dynamic query in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

i do not know if this has answer or not but i couldn't fix my issue .

```
Shift.updateOne({
                $and: [{phone: number}, {statusSH: "open"}, {
                    'order.startTime': start,
                    'order.finishTime': finish
                },{'order.orders.5.stat':"false"}]
            },{'$set': {'order.orders.5.stat': "true"}},function (error,update) {
                if (update){
                    
                }
            });
```

this 'order.orders.5.stat' works fine . but i don't know how i can use dynamic index . like if i have a "var index" where should i add that to query . it seems if i 'order.orders.'+index+'.stat' i get error .

All helps will be appreciated. Thank You.

Edit :

doc should be like this

```
    { 
        "_id": "5f52745e77abf55e80228379",
        "phone": "09898989666",
        "final": true,
        "statusSH": "open",
        "created_time": "1599239262",
        "__v": 0
        "order": {
                  "startTime": "139912292135",
                  "finishTime": "139912292240",
                  "orders": [
                   {
                    "_id": "5f52745e77abf55e8022837a",
                    "stat": "false",
                   },
                   {
                    "_id": "5f52745e77abf55e8022837b",
                   "stat": "false",
                    }
                    ]
                }
              }
```

Comment: @turivishal i did

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `[]` when you concat key of object,

```
var index = "5";
var number = "09898989666";
var start = "139912292135";
var finish = "139912292240";
Shift.updateOne({
    $and: [
        { phone: number }, 
        { statusSH: "open" }, 
        {
            'order.startTime': start,
            'order.finishTime': finish
        }, 
        { ['order.orders.' + index + '.stat']: "false" } // change here
    ]
}, 
{
    '$set': { ['order.orders.' + index + '.stat']: "true" } // change here
}, 
function(error, update) {
    if (update) {
        console.log(update)
    }
});
```

Comment: how can i use index ?

Answer (score 1):

```
   x='order.orders.{}.stat'.format(index)



   .... x:"false"
```

Comment: okay , understood. Its because we are concatenating a string with an integer. I will fix it

Comment: dude but it didn't work either  :(  when i try to use  +  it gets me error . try this you will get it too .

Comment: so where should i put index ?

Comment: replace 5 with index

Comment: Put all these into  a varibal , b4 the function and try callling that variable here

Comment: it's funny that even i can't call the variable

Comment: it do not realize the variable

Comment: btw , thanks for your time , i will keep looking for solution;

Comment: Are you sure , your syntax is correct > I havent done using mongodb , but i feel order.orders[5].stat feels more logical